# Can't display image on ImageView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

I am working on an android application in which I want to display the user details which includes the user's profile picture. Right now I was just trying to display the chosen image from the gallery on the `ImageView`. I searched over the Internet and found the following code but it doesn't seems to work for me. Here's the code:

```
public class UserProfile extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
TextView etUsername, etGender, etMob, etMail;
Button bLogout;
ImageView imageView;

private static final int RESULT_LOAD = 999;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile_layout,container,false);

    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.userImage);

    etUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etGender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etGender);
    etMob = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etMob);
    etMail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etMail);
    bLogout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bLogout);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD);
        }
    });

    bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            userLocalStore.clearUserData();
            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SplashScreenTabbed.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
        }
    });
    try {
        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(getActivity());

        User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
        etUsername.setText(user.username);
        etGender.setText(user.gender);
        etMob.setText(user.mobile);
        etMail.setText(user.email);
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Can't Connect To Server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try{
    // When an Image is picked
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        String path = getPathFromCameraData(data, this.getActivity());

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hey pick your image first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e)
    {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    }
}

public static String getPathFromCameraData(Intent data, Context context) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return picturePath;
}
```

}

This code works when I am using it in an activity but it doesn't works in a fragment. If I pick the image from gallery then it goes into to `catch()` block or else it prints the message from the `else` part. Please help me out guys!

Comment: Just to see if method is triggered, try to move the onActivityResult inside hosting Activity

Comment: what  was the exception.

Comment: @Shine did you even read the whole question? He said it goes to **catch** or to **else.**

Answer (score 2):

Here is my example. This is the tested code.

```
public class ImageSelector extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.createevent,container,false);

    imgcover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.newcover_img);
    btnupload = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.newcover_upload);

    btnupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }
    });
}

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
    {
        Uri selectedImg = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImg,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        imgcover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newcover_img);
        imgcover .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                cursor.close();
    }
  }
```

It help's you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;

imageView_profilepic = (ImageView).findViewById(R.id.imageView_Profile_Pic);
imageView_profilepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            }
        });


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data
                decodeUri(data.getData());

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

public void decodeUri(Uri uri) {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFD = null;
        try {
            parcelFD = getActivity().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            FileDescriptor imageSource = parcelFD.getFileDescriptor();

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(imageSource, null, o);

            // the new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                    break;
                }
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(imageSource, null, o2);

            imageView_profilepic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // handle errors
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle errors
        } finally {
            if (parcelFD != null)
                try {
                    parcelFD.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // ignored
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a silly error/exception:
`09-17 21:09:46.381    2292-2292/app.usrete.jayant.delvemitt W/System.err﹕ java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/16 from pid=2292, uid=10062 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`
, I didn't added the read permission in the manifest. Adding it resolved the issue. By the way, Thank you guys for helping me out.